# TTFB delay issue in running spring boot microservice jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I am trying to implement microservices using spring boot. It was really hard to find the root cause but when found, the root cause is pretty weird.

Please suggest what steps should I take to resolve this TTFB delay I get when I hit the API endpoint of the running jar of spring boot microservice.

**Root Cause:** When I run the microservice in any IDE (eg.: NetBeans), and then I hit the API endpoint of the running microservice, I get the server JSON response in milliseconds i.e. TTFB waiting is in milliseconds.
When I build the same microservice using maven and run the jar file generated in the target directory, using `java -jar microservice.jar`, I get the server json response in 4-5 seconds i.e. TTFB waiting time increases to 4-5 seconds, causing serious performance issue.

Database used: MongoDB
Server: Embedded Tomcat 8.0.33
Spring Boot version: 1.3.5

Comment: It depends on your network connection with cloud.

Comment: Nope, not a network connection issue. It seems an embedded tomcat issue, but don't know where and how to solve it.

Comment: Is it only for the first request or for all the requests

Comment: First 2 requests if sent just after running the jar, it takes milliseconds. But after that if I wait for like 5 seconds before sending the 3rd request, then it is served with TTFB of 4-5 seconds delay.

Comment: Then some requests sent just after sending 3rd request, is served within milliseconds, but if I waited 5 seconds before sending each of other requests, is served with same delay in TTFB (4-5 seconds)

Comment: Can you check your logic

Comment: Fixed the issue by upgrading the spring boot version from 1.3.5 to 2.2.1